# reduxForm - FieldsArray : fields.push({}) not working

Tags: redux, redux-form

I m trying to populate an Array Form using the component FieldArray of reduxForm

```
<FieldArray name="testArray"
component={renderArray}
/>
```

where

```
let testArray = [{}];
export const renderArray= ({fields}) => (
        <ul>

                {window.alert("Array - size ="+_.size(fields))}

                {_.size(fields) === 1 ? fields.push({}) : null}

                {window.alert("Array - size ="+_.size(fields))}

                {fields.map((otherFiscalResidencyCountry, index) => (
                    <li key={index}>test</li>

                ))}

            </ul>)
```

I was waiting that the fields size be 2 after doing the fields.push({}). but I ve got size = 1 ...

Here is a debugging screenshot :

[image]

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue using the push on array instead of the push  action creator of redux-form

so here is the solution :

```
   testArray = testArray || []; // this initialize my array

   fields.getAll().push({})
```

instead of

```
fields.push({})
```

Comment: In my case it was that I just forgot to connect redux-form reducer in store config